# How do I specify a mediatype of text/plain;charset=UTF-8 in a Spring Boot Test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, kotlin, mockmvc

Here's my test :

```
 @Test
 fun `test config properties`() {
    mockMvc.request(HttpMethod.GET,"someUrl") {
        accept = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN
    }.andExpect {
        status { isOk }
        content { contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN) }
    }
}
```

and it fails with this:

> Expected :text/plain Actual   :text/plain;charset=UTF-8

This is using the Kotlin DSL for MockMVC.

How do I change the accept to allow for charset=UTF-8 ?

Comment: There is one factory method which accepts custom value. Try MediaType.valueOf("text/plain;charset=UTF-8")

Comment: Great that works - thanks. If you change that comment to an answer I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I have added an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is one factory method which accepts custom value. Try:

```
MediaType.valueOf("text/plain;charset=UTF-8")
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the constructor accepting the encoding as a parameter:

```java
new MediaType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

Answer (score 3):

If charset is not the objective of the test Spring Boot provides more flexible assertion of the `content-type` using `contentTypeCompatibleWith()`:

For instance, in Kotlin DSL it would look like this:

```kotlin
mockMvc.get("/") {
    accept = TEXT_HTML
}.andExpect {
    content {
        contentTypeCompatibleWith(TEXT_HTML)
        // ... more assertions here...
    }
}
```